# Multiplication by $m$ isogenies of elliptic curves in characteristic $p$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, positive-characteristic

I've been attempting to prove [some comments I've read on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7318/etale-cohomology-and-l-adic-tate-modules/7359#7359) by myself for my undergrad thesis regarding étale morphisms of elliptic curves. My definition of an étale morphism is taken from [Milne's notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf) (page 19) which roughly says that for a field $K$ with algebraic closure $\bar{K}$, a morphism $\phi: X\rightarrow Y$ of varieties (all defined over $K$) is étale at $P\in X(K)$ if it is étale at $P$ when we consider everything as being defined over $\bar{K}$. In this case being étale means the induced linear map $d_P\phi: T_P X \rightarrow T_{\phi(P)}Y$ (as $\bar{K}$-vector spaces) on tangent spaces is an isomorphism. We say $\phi$ is étale if it is étale at every point.

Assuming I've done things correctly I've managed to prove that for an elliptic curve $E$ over a field $K$,

1. If $\operatorname{char}(K)=0$ then every multiplication-by-$m$ isogeny $[m]:E\rightarrow E$ is étale;
2. If $\operatorname{char}(K) = p>0$ then $[m]:E\rightarrow E$ is étale as long as $m$ is not a multiple of $p$.

The way I proved this (using Theorem III.4.10(c) in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*) broke down in characteristic $p$ when I looked at isogenies of the form $[np]$ because I could not show these isogenies had to be separable. Initially I had just supposed they had to be zero, but I don't think this is right. Indeed I've seen that an object called a "$p$-divisible group" apparently captures $p$-torsion in characteristic $p$ better than Tate $p$-modules, and this suggests that in fact these morphisms aren't always zero. So isogenies of the form $[np]$ can be finite, and I guess could potentially even be étale. I really have no intuition in characteristic $p$ though.

If anyone could provide me with an answer to whether multiplying by (a multiple of) $p$ on an elliptic curve in characteristic $p$ is étale or not - or some pointers on how to prove this - I would really appreciate it.

**Edit**: I've been reminded of theorem III.4.2(a) in AEC in a comment below which says that for nonzero $m$ the multiplication-by-$m$ isogeny is never zero, no matter what $m$ or the characteristic of the field are. Thus the isogenies $[np]$ are nonzero even in characteristic $p$. Whether or not they are étale, however, is still open.

**Further edit**: it has been pointed out in the comments that the multiplication by $p$ isogeny in characteristic $p$ can be purely inseparable (in the case that the elliptic curve is "supersingular"). Hence in some cases we can't apply theorem III.4.10c to deduce they are unramified, which is what I needed for the other parts of this proof. So I think the question boils down to whether or not these morphisms are unramified and how to show this in a different way.

Comment: Indeed the isogeny $[m]:E\to E$ is nonzero as long as $m\neq 0$, even if $E$ is defined over a field of characteristic dividing $m$ (this is proposition III.4.2a in Silverman). $[p]:E\to E$ where $E$ lives over a field of characteristic $p$ is purely inseparable, see Silverman theorem V.3.1a.

Comment: Thanks for both of these references - I had completely forgotten about III.4.2a! But does pure inseparability have any bearing on being étale?

Comment: I don't believe inseparability is incompatible with \'{e}tale-ness of the morphism, I simply wanted to include that fact as well since you stated that you couldn't show that the isogenies needed to be separable in the question - and they are not (perhaps you meant some other sort of separability?).

Comment: @Stahl Right, this makes sense - and I meant the usual definition of separability. I suppose I wasn't sure whether or not they were separable and didn't know of this theorem in chapter V. Now I know they are purely inseparable it follows that any proof of these isogenies being étale has to go along different lines to my attempt.

Comment: The comments at the top of page 6 [here](http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/2007/tmfproc/Chapter04/henriques.pdf) might be useful to you.

Comment: @Stahl this is really helpful (and suggests the question might be more difficult than I thought). So the only place in which "étaleness" has a chance of failing is for supersingular curves, but (as of the top of page 6) it still looks like both cases are possible. I will do some reading on supersingular curves and see what I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [a reference](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BF9) which has the required result with proof (which I've copied here). I claim no originality.

**Lemma (38.9.9):** Let $k$ be a field. Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $k$. Then $[d]:A\to A$ is étale if and only if $d$ is invertible in $k$.

**Proof:** Observe that $[d](x+y)=[d](x)+[d](y)$. Since translation by a point is an automorphism of $A$, we see that the set of points where $[d]:A\to A$ is étale is either empty or equal to $A$ (some details omitted). Thus it suffices to check whether $[d]$ is étale at the unit $e\in A(k)$. Since we know that $[d]$ is finite locally free ([Lemma 38.9.8](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BFG)) to see that it is étale at $e$ is equivalent to proving that $d[d]:T_{A/k,e}\to T_{A/k,e}$ is injective. See Varieties, [Lemma 32.14.8](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B2G) and Morphisms, [Lemma 28.36.16](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GV). By [Lemma 38.6.4](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BF5) we see that $d[d]$ is given by multiplication by $d$ on $T_{A/k,e}$.

Also, [here](https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~bakkerbe/faltings2.pdf) (proposition 3.7) shows that for abelian varieties, an isogeny being étale is equivalent to it being separable is equivalent to it having étale kernel (meaning, a kernel which is étale as a subgroup scheme). So, it turns out that inseparability *does* have bearing on being étale, at least in the case of isogenies between abelian varieties.

Comment: Thank you, this does the job! I will take some time to understand these general lemmas, but I see the general idea and how it works for elliptic curves.