# Categories of étale coverings of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, elliptic-curves, etale-cohomology

Let $(E,\mathcal{O})$ be an elliptic curve over a (perfect) field $K$ and let $\textbf{Cov}(E,\mathcal{O})$ denote the category of finite pointed étale covers of $E$ from smooth varieties where the distinguished point $\mathcal{O}'$ on each cover is a $K$-point. One can show that each of these covering varieties must be an elliptic curve $(E', \mathcal{O}')$ and the covering maps are then isogenies of elliptic curves. The morphisms $(E', \phi)\rightarrow (E'', \psi)$ in this category between two finite étale covers are *pointed* morphisms of algebraic varieties, and thus become finite étale isogenies in their own right (since the "base change" of an étale morphism is étale).

Let $\textbf{Cov}_{\mathbb{N}} (E,\mathcal{O})\subseteq\textbf{Cov}(E,\mathcal{O})$ denote the full subcategory consisting of multiplication-by-$m$ isogenies $[m]:E\rightarrow E$ for $m\in K^\times$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616121/multiplication-by-m-isogenies-of-elliptic-curves-in-characteristic-p/1616943#1616943) other question of mine). I'm wondering if there is a functor $\Delta: \textbf{Cov}(E,\mathcal{O})\rightarrow\textbf{Cov}_{\mathbb{N}}(E,\mathcal{O})$ sending each isogeny $\phi: E'\rightarrow E$ to the precomposition with the dual isogeny $[\deg\phi] = \phi\circ\hat{\phi}:E\rightarrow E$?

More precisely, if $f: (E', \phi)\rightarrow(E'', \psi)$ is a morphism in $\textbf{Cov}(E,\mathcal{O})$, does there exist a (functorial) morphism $\Delta(f):E\rightarrow E$ in $\textbf{Cov}_{\mathbb{N}}(E,\mathcal{O})$ such that the following diagram commutes?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a bit, I think I've solved this: set $\Delta(f) = [\deg f]:E\rightarrow E$. Then it's easy to see that $\zeta: = f\circ \hat{\phi} - \hat{\psi}\circ \Delta(f)$ is a morphism $E\rightarrow E''$ whose image is contained in the kernel of $\psi$. Now $\psi$ is a finite étale morphism so $\ker\psi$ is a finite subgroup of $E''$ of order $\deg\psi$. Since any morphism of smooth curves is either surjective or constant, it follows that $\zeta$ is a constant map. Now in $\textbf{Cov}(E, \mathcal{O})$ the morphism $f$ was *pointed* (i.e. is an isogeny), and therefore it follows that $\zeta$ is an isogeny. Thus $\zeta$ is identically zero, and therefore the diagram above commutes.

In particular with $\Delta(f) = [\deg f]$ we get $f \circ \hat{\phi} = \hat{\psi}\circ \Delta(f)$. The multiplicative property of degrees of compositions of morphisms implies that $\Delta$ is the functor we wanted.